# Recursive python call does not verify all the options

Tags: python, recursion

> Build a recursive function that verifies that for each 
>   `i<len(lis)/2 : lis[i]+lis[len(lis)-i-1] = x`

```
def controlTest(list,x):
#@param list: list of integers
#@param x: integer
#@return: bool
 for i in range(0,len(list)/2):
  if list[i]+list[len(list)-i-1]==x:  
   return controlTest(list[1:len(list)-1],x)
  else:
   return list
```

I expect the output of this function to be an empy list [], but the for-loop jumps the steps of the recursive call

> Examples: if `list= [1, 5, 3, 6, 4, 8]` and `x = 9`, the function returns an empty list [] because 1+8 = 5+4 = 3+6
>   = 9

Comment: How do you know it jumps steps of recursion?

Comment: you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: `controlTest = lambda lst, x: lst if not lst or lst[0] + lst[-1] != x else controlTest(lst[1:-1], x)`

Comment: You `return` on the first iteration of the `for` loop, that can't be right?

Comment: @chris, the list doesn't have to be that specific one

Comment: @tripleee, yes it is:
being a recursive call that has to verify the condition in the if-statement, it returns the list without the first element and the last one (every time the function is called recursively).

Comment: But there is no point in creating a loop if you exit it on the first iteration. The code probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to return the inner part of the list which does not satisfy this criterion, the following would work:

```
def controlTest(l, x):
    if len(l) < 2:
        return []  # base case
    elif l[0] + l[-1] != x:
        return l  # failure
    else:
        return controlTest(l[1:-1], x) # recursion
```

This could be made more brief, but I expand the definition to put emphasis on the missing elements. In a recursive function, looping is generally not necessary, as the recursion itself provides the looping effect.

- First we provide our base case, which "breaks the loop" so to say, in which we have traversed half of the list.
- Second we provide the return value for the failing case, where the result was not what we were testing for, which will then be propagated up the call stack from the recursive calls
- Next we recurse if the condition holds for the inner part of the list.

This returns what I think is expected from the question:

```
>>> controlTest([1,5,3,6,4,8], 9)
[]
>>> controlTest([1,5,4,6,4,8], 9)
[4, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks, i forgot the baseline scenarios

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the input array is length 0, the for loop never runs and so you have no return statement. That way if the check is successful, the last recursive call is run on an empty array and doesn't return anything, so you get an answer of `None`.

I also had to an add a cast to int on the line:

```
len(list)/2 -> int(len(list)/2)
```

to get the code to run.

You could just add an extra `return` at the end outside of the for loop like below, or you could do a check for empty arrays.

```
def controlTest(list,x):
#@param list: list of integers
#@param x: integer
#@return: bool
    for i in range(0,int(len(list)/2)):
        if list[i]+list[len(list)-i-1]==x:
            return controlTest(list[1:len(list)-1],x)
        else:
            return list
    return []
```

Comment: I think Bob Zimmermann's answer is a better way of solving this problem, but have left my answer here as I think it explains why your code isn't working the way you expected.